# gradle : setting a subproject property from another subproject

Tags: gradle

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':projectA',':projectB'
```

**projectA/build.gradle**

```
task task1()  {
    doFirst {
        println 'setting project.ext.testProperty1'
        project(':projectB').ext.testProperty1 = 'MyProperty'
    }
}

task task2 (dependsOn: ['task1', ':projectB:task3']) {
    doLast {
        println "Executed project B Task3 from projectA task2"
    }
}
```

**projectB/build.gradle**

```
task task3() {
    doLast {
        println "task3 from projectB"
        println project(':projectB').ext.testProperty1
        if(project(':projectB').ext.hasProperty("testProperty1")) {
            ext.prop1  = project.property("testProperty1")
            println "+++++++++If : Clause++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        } else {
            println "+++++++++Else  :Clause++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I call gradle task2 the output I get is always

```
$ ../gradlew task2
:projectA:task1
setting project.ext.testProperty1
:projectB:task3
task3 from projectB
MyProperty
+++++++++Else  :Clause++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
:projectA:task2
Executed project B Task3 from projectA task2
```

It never goes into the "If" Clause, what am I missing, It even seems to get the ext.property testProperty1 in ProjectB but hasProperties does not seem to evaluate it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the "ext" out from the code

```
if(project(':projectB').ext.hasProperty("testProperty1"))
```

and instead change it to

```
if(project(':projectB').hasProperty("testProperty1"))
```

Then it goes to the if clause, I have no idea why having ext at readtime is causing an issue when we can use it at writetime.